# Is it possible to select an image (or other element) by comparative size in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select an image or other elements by some size criteria, e.g., large than some pixels in X or Y dimension?

How?

I've found @media descriptors which do allow comparison operators, but these apply to the display area as a whole.

My goal is to write a styling rule for images which applies only above a certain threshold, say, 100px.  Say, this style, which makes sense for content images but not for small items elsewhere in a page.  The stylesheets are being applied to external pages over which I've no control of their contents and generally cannot rewrite or script-process them:

```css
img {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #888;
    /* Grey */
    box-shadow: 6px 10px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* Sepia */
    box-shadow: 6px 10px 8px rgba(128, 128, 96, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: That's not possible, you have to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: @onetrickpony: I cannot edit the source, so adding classes isn't possible.  Depending on the source I can test on classes.  I fixed an immediate problem using "img:not(.classname)" for example, where that class name reliably matched my exclusion case.

Comment: @Dropout I suppose I could for some instances.  I'm mostly 1) writing Stylebot styles to fix broken site layout and 2) writing CSS on Dreamwidth (a LiveJournals site) to handle RSS feeds.  In the former case I could use something like Greasemonkey to write my own JS (which I'd have to learn).  In the latter, CSS is all I've got.

Comment: @Dr.EdwardMorbius well in case you can use jQuery take a look at the css() method.. If you don't provide a second value it returns it - `$("#yourElement").css("width")`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery functions could perform your desired job:

```
function check_image_width (image, length, type, className)
{
   if(type='greater') // then compare by the minimum width
   {
      if($(image).width() > length)
        {
          $(image).addClass(className);
        }
    }
    if(type='lesser') // then compare by the minimum width
   {
      if($(image).width() < length)
        {
          $(image).addClass(className);
        }
   }
}
```

I've gone just very fast for above function. It could be much more versatile...

Answer (score 0):

If img have width/height attributes and certain fixed values (eg 32px icon, 60px gravatars, 100px thumbnails and "all others") you can use attribute selectors.

```
img{ /*"other" images*/}
img[width="100"]{ /*thumbnails rules*/}
img[width="60"]{ /*gravatars rules*/}
img[width="32"]{ /*icons rules*/}
```

If you don't have width/height you could also use the URL to select them. Probably you could have urls with fragments like ".../images/style/thumbnail/..." that can be also used:

```
img{ /*"other" images*/}
img[src*="images/style/thumbnail"] { /*thumbnail rules*/}
img[src*="www.gravatarsite.kom/images"] { /*gravatars rules*/}
img[src*="css/icons32"] { /*icons rules*/}
```

Check [w3c attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#attribute-selectors), you can also match start/end patterns and combine them.

Comment: Right.  I can (and do) use this for some common image sizes (1x1 especially).  However there are a lot of x,y combinations from 1 <= n <= 100 ;-)

I also can and do display/suppress by origin in some instances, though that also gets messy.

These are generally user-side stylesheets (or RSS stylesheets), and I'm applying them to arbitrary content from the Web, so what I'm service is really runs the gamut.